# Too high TTFB on Laravel's API requests

Tags: laravel, optimization, react-redux, xmlhttprequest, httprequest

When i executes a HTTP-request to Laravel's API (e.g. `/api/devices`) wia Postman, the execution time is ~1000ms.

When same HTTP-request executes from Front on React-Redux, the TTFB (time to first byte) gains to 3000-7000ms.

SQL query logging shows times up to 50ms per query (~10 queries), but Enter point's (`public/index.php`) execute time is only 1-3ms.

Where should i look for a problem??

Comment: what about you're environment, how are you running the server ? on a VM, localy or on a dedicated machine ?

Comment: @N69S Server on local machine on Windows. Serves with `php artisan serve` (Laravel development server) and Postgres (on OpenServer).

Answer (score 0):

Use [Barryvdh's debug bar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar).

It will provide full profiling information for your app and let you know where the slow-down is.

Comment: Barryvdh's debug bar not give more useful information about why TTFB so high. Metrics which debug bar shows are similar to in my question.

Comment: If that is the case, something else on your system is the culprit. In windows environments, AV software can often cause the startup of large frameworks to be very slow. Can you test your same code base on a different environment? Or if you have AV software, *temporarily disable* it to see if that is the fact?

Comment: On Ubuntu server is same problem.